# Elastix call recordings

Tags: asterisk

Нужно выдать группе права на прослушивание и скачивание звонков, галочку на  call recordings поставил, но у них загружается пустая таблица без единой записи, под администратором там куча записей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в файле: var/www/html/libs/paloSantoACL.class.php

В функции:

```
function isUserAdministratorGroup($username)
```

после строчки:

```
$is = array_search('1', $arrGroup);
```

Добавить следующий код:

```
if(isset($arrGroup['Operator']))
$is=true;
```

После этого все пользователи группы Operator смогут просматривать отчет по всем звонкам, а также прослушивать все разговоры.

http://zhutov.ru/post/5/